# jQuery loader until redirect after Stripe Payment

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payment API on my website and it works great. However, once the payment is complete, a customer is still on the checkout page until the order confirmation/receipt page is loaded. I do not want a user to leave the page until the receipt page loads. It takes awhile to load because order tables are being updated and an email is being sent.

Since the payment happens in a Strip modal and the modal closes once payment is successful, I am not sure how to implement a loader before the page redirects to receipt page.

Would I need to invoke the loader before the call the Stripe, on the Stripe button press? Any input would be helpful. I can provide my website's name if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use Checkout's ["custom integration"](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) for this, so you could define your own `token` callback function.

In the callback, you could send the token to your backend in an AJAX request and display some sort of waiting state indicator to the customer while waiting for your server's reply.

Here's a basic example of a custom integration with an AJAX request: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/ym0k4t9f/

Answer (score 1):

Without custom ingratiation use the onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  $('.loader').show();
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me to activate Gaspare Sganga's excellent LoadingQverlay script. After my user clicks pay on the Stripe overlay (legacy checkout) this shows spinning dots until the confirm page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Is more easy.

Depends if iframe exist or not...after de payment before go to the submit page...<
When the button is loaded, the iframe exist. After that...the iframe dissapear...at that moment before redirect, we show the css loader.

```js
 var clickeado = "no";
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#stripeform .stripe-button-el').on('click', function()
        {
          clickeado = "yes";    
          ckeckCountIframe();       
    }); 
    function ckeckCountIframe()
        {
            const interval = setInterval(() =>
            {

              if(!$('.stripe_checkout_app').is(":visible"))
              {
                //console.log("Stripe modal is hidden");
                //document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].disabled=false;
                if (clickeado == "yes")
                {

                  if ($('.stripe_checkout_app').length > 0)
                  {
                    console.log('iframe exists');
                    console.log("GoBack");
                    document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].disabled=true;
                    window.location = "../store_checkout.php";
                    clearInterval(interval);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    console.log('iframe no exists');
                    console.log("Loader ON");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                  }

                }
              }

            }, 1000)
          }
 });
```